# Django: how to get the most selling course using django filter?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-orm

i have a course models and user are allowed to purchase this courses, now i want to filter the courses by the most selling course, i have tried using django agreegate but it seems not to be giving me what i want or maybe i am not doing it the right way.

i have models.py that is storing the courses

```
class Course(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    course_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    course_creayor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

i also have this model that stores the courses that are purchased and enrolled in

```
class UserCourse(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , null = False , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course , null = False , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

i dont know how to write the view to filter the courses by the most selling
from the image below you can see that `learn angular updated` is the most selling course for the creator `destiny`. so how do i filter this for each user, thier most selling course?

[image]

Comment: How do you define the "most selling course"? Is it the course with most number of users?

Comment: @P.Naoum yes a course with the most number of users

Comment: It looks like these are not `Course`s, but `UserCourse`s in your image?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes it's not `course` but it is `UserCourse`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you are correct

Comment: Do you want get the course id with the maximum sold case, given a specific user?

Comment: @DavidLu  I am looking to create a view,
that will display a list,
where each element of the list is the Course Creator and their top-selling Course.


And the output also need to include the number of sales for that top-selling course

Comment: Can you add `UserSerializer` here? Then I'll add the solution in it.

Comment: @DavidLu I have added the User to the model `Course` hopefully that's what you mean by UserSerializer

Comment: If you want to implement Rest API using DRF, you should create a serializer for each models.

Comment: @DavidLu i am not looking to create a rest api, i just wanna list of the top selling course of a user in thier dashboard and i want to write a view probably would be done using a `filter()` but i dnon't know how to go about achiveing this

Comment: @p.Naoum I'm still working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try annotating the course counts like this:

```py
course_counts = UserCourse.objects.values("course").annotate(count=models.Count("course"))
```

Then sorting:

```py
sorted_courses = sorted(course_counts, key=lambda x: x['count'],reverse=True)
```

You will have the `sorted_courses[0]` containing the highest one and you can retrieve the `UUID` from the dict